# Fastest ways to do backups: FTP, rsync, Robocopy, SMB/CIFS, etc?

Tags: backup, rsync

Im looking for methods to do (incremental) backups and sync from and to NAS over LAN and VPN.

Im having trouble finding couple implementations between Linux and Windows.

My Linux NAS boxes have rsync which Ive read is pretty good. But Ive seen so many server implementations in Windows which seem to be difficult to implement.

Other than that, is there anything else? Im doing right now with Robocopy and SMB/CIFS with a network mounted drive but I feel the transfer performance is slow.

What recommendations are out there?

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look to proper backup programs like Amanda (http://www.amanda.org/) or Bacula (http://blog.bacula.org/).

Comment: These look more like Linux tools than Windows...I cant install Linux tools on a NAS box.

Comment: These are cross platform tools, except for the server which usually is placed on Linux. In any casi probably you can perform backups over mounted FS of NAS. Normally NAS ships with NDMP for performing backups.

Comment: You should probably get some metrics instead of relying on your feelings on the speed. Your bottleneck may be the connection to the networked drive and not the tool or protocol being used.

Comment: Bacula is really cool tool, although a bit hard to setup. I am currently using backuppc, and storing backups at NAS via NFS. Backups are done using rsync over ssh.

Comment: @BelminFernandez I tested it and it goes slow as well. A lot of Linux solutions are out there but nothing really 100% Windows.